# w3wp Diagnostics Report: List of modules compiled in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I'm looking at a report from a process dump I generated in a production server. The Asp.Net Application is compiled in Release mode and deployed to an Azure app service. But, when I look at the report generated, it has a section 'List of modules compiled in Debug mode' I see a lot of `App_Web_xxxxxxx` (where x is a random character) and also another with the name `Microsoft_Web_Compilation_Snapshots`

Is it normal to have all this modules compiled in Debug mode if I compiled my app in Release mode? what are all those App_Web_xxxxxxx modules, are they precompiled view or something?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. Take a look in your web.config for `<system.codedom>`; add `/optimize+ /debug-` to the `compilerOptions` attribute.

After this change, the assemblies went from

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
```

to

```
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
```

EDIT:
To answer your question specifically, these are the JIT'ed views in your application.  At runtime, it will compile these views.  It appears that regardless of your `<system.compilation>` setting, it compiles these in debug mode.  Here's some discussion I had found that seems relevant: [https://forums.asp.net/t/1625220.aspx?Razor+compilation](https://forums.asp.net/t/1625220.aspx?Razor%20compilation)

If you need to know more of these compile flags, you can find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/listed-alphabetically)(for c# anyways).